# how to retrieve due fee month wise student?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm try to fetch due month which, students not submitted there fee in his profile its show like your fee is due in this month,example- if a student not paid his/her fee in february and january then its his account that  you fee is due in february and january please submit fee.I'm able to fetch all students who not submitted fee but how to show month(<=current month) all previous month fee dues

here is my code for profile

```
 public function show($reg_no = null)
{
    $s = Student::where('reg_no', $reg_no)->with('courses','states','sections','city','ccity','sstates')->first();

    return view('students.student',compact('s'));
}
```

for students who not submitted fee in current month all students

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$query = Student::where('status',1)->whereDoesntHave('subscriptions', function ($queryt) use($dt) {

           $queryt->whereMonth('created_at','=',$dt->month);

        })->with('courses')->paginate(15);
```

and here is my subscriptions table [image]

Comment: I'm not sure where is your fee, but if I understand, I think you should create a table where you have user_id, fee, due_month, paid. Then, when you query your student, add a with 'fee' and make your condition into this fee query. So you can say addition all fee where user_id = the_user_id, due_month <= current month, where paid = false.

If it's what your looking for, I can make a more detailled answer.

Comment: I edited my questions where u can see i have subscriptions table whcih detaild i fil.Now here i Want to retrive students subscriptions not submited in months<=current month and show them profile. And also what as what u saying also please share.

Comment: @Vipin Kumar do you wish to get current month??

Comment: actually I want list which students not submitted his/her fee last all month like if a students not submitted there fee january and february then its show them in his/her account like you fee is due of february and january please pay your fee.

Comment: how do you know if the students have paid his fee?

Comment: @ElieMorin in my question u can see that i fetch all student who does not submited their fee but problem and in there account i show that on that day u have paid your fee

Comment: In your code `$queryt->whereMonth('created_at','=',$dt->month);` This only compare current month, so your not looking for past due fee. If you do another function that calculate the total due fee somewhere else and you have the total in this result. You just have to have a function that display OK if the due fee is = 0.

Comment: yes i also added a for filter  `$month = $request->month;  $query = Student::where('status',1)->whereDoesntHave('subscriptions', function ($queryt) use($month) {

               $queryt->whereMonth('created_at','=',$month);

            })->with('courses'); `  now by this , we fetch previous month students who not submitted fee

Comment: @ElieMorin now should i add a extra colunm for due_fee (0 or 1)?

Comment: run this in artisan `php artisan make:migration edit_tablename`. Then go in the migration then make a new column. When your change are ready run in terminal `php artisan migrate`. There you go. Look into the link for help and information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

Comment: @ElieMorin so after this i edited my subscriptions table ` $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('other_fee')->nullable();
            $table->string('tution_fee');
            $table->string('late_fee')->nullable();
            $table->string('development_fee')->nullable();
            $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('paid');
            $table->timestamps();
`

Comment: If your table already exist, don't recreate each column. just do `$table->boolean("paid")->after("remark");` into up function. Into down section, do `$table->dropcolumn("paid");`

Comment: so here is problem that so how to fetch last month if he not submitted the fee in there account

Comment: What are the result of your query?

Comment: how to do query ?

Comment: @VipinKumar Sorry for the delay. I want you to do `dd($s);` and `dd($query);` and show us the result of this. To know what datas you retrieve, then you'll be able to understand the structure and show the data you need.

Comment: @ElieMorin how to do query like what query code should be

Comment: @VipinKumar You said `I'm able to fetch all students who not submitted fee but how to show month`. So now you want to show it, So, put a `dd($s);` between `$s = Student::where('reg_no', $reg_no)->with('courses','states','sections','city','ccity','sstates')->first();` and `return view('students.student',compact('s'));`. Go to the page using your browser and you will see the structure. Then you can manage to code the way to access the data you want.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vipin733/438bf3c016a815ee30b1bc91e9966d78

Comment: @VipinKumar So, as you can see, you got the structure of your query. Now, it's straigth foward. Simply do this `echo $Student->subcriptions->tution_fee;` or `$fee = $Student->subcriptions->tution_fee + $Student->subcriptions->late_fee; echo $fee;`. I'm not sure how you really want to display thoses values, but you can understand how to use them now.

Comment: @VipinKumar Maybe you will need to do a loop... But all this is pretty basic, so maybe you should refer to documentation of php and laravel.

Comment: @ElieMorin i think u did not got my questioned, Yes I'm able to show the all fee submitted in his account  but problem is that how do i query to not submited month fee if a student not submitted fee in his jan and feb . then how to show that "your last month jan , feb fee is due please submit the fee"

Comment: @VipinKumar Since you can access the value, make a function that will handle it. Make an array, then in a foreach loop analyse if the month is paid, if not, push a message into an array, then into the view, do antoher loop that will show every message. If it's what your looking for, I'll make you an exemple as an anwser.

Comment: @ElieMorin that's the question i'm asking what is the function

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you an example, but don't just copy paste, because this code is only to help you to understand how to achieve it. You'll need to make some change to fit in your app.

```
$messages = array();
foreach ($Student->subcriptions as subcription) {
    if ($subcription->late_fee != null) {
        $month = $subcription->month->month(); // I'm not sure if Carbon will handle this part. If not, you'll need to do an explode of $subcription->month then take the $month[1]...
        if ($month == 1) {$month = 'January';}
        if ($month == 2) {$month = 'February';}
        ... //Do it for every month...
        $message = 'Your fee are due for '.$month; //Or you can only push the month then into the view then implode the array.
        array_push($messages, $message);
    }
}
```

Into your view, if you are using blade, you simply do this where you want to show the messages. Don't forget to pass $messages to the view.

```
@foreach($messages as $message)
    <span>{{$message}}</span>
@endforeach
```

There is multiple way to do what you want. But this will show every month where the student have late_fee not null. Now adapt it to your code.

Don't forget that if you don't want something like:

```
Your fee are due for January.
Your fee are due for February.
Your fee are due for Mars.
....
```

Look for implode of the messages array without adding `Your fee are due for` into the loop then don't use the for each loop into the view, simply display the new imploded variable.

Comment: late_fee or paid because i'm added extra column as u said

Comment: @VipinKumar Use paid instead, but as I said, this code is only there to help you understand how it work. You need to change it to be sure it do what you want into your app.

Comment: its showing errors "FatalThrowableError in SubscriptionController.php line 46:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' "

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vipin733/4b39ecedb463b2a6ca36c14006504139 here is code please review

Comment: ErrorException in SubscriptionController.php line 38:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: its not working returning array "[]"  dd($messages);

Comment: @VipinKumar At this point, you need to verify your code and where do you try to use `dd($messages);`... We can't really help if you just saying "There is an error there..."

Comment: its showing wrong message(I'm i dont want this, its showing message when i pay fee of january the showing message "Your fee are due for January." but i just paid fee of january month it giving me inverse result but when i "$subcription->tution_fee == null" its dd "[]"  any idea

Comment: @VipinKumar 1. I don't know where you try to use `dd();`. I use it into controller before a return. 2. I said that you need to make some change in the code I posted. You are the one who know the logic of your application. So, if you don't change late_fee when some one pay it, it will continue to display that your fee are due.

Comment: please have look https://gist.github.com/vipin733/dd548204e47d922d846a53df92eba16f

Comment: @VipinKumar Right now, you are looking for paid fee at line 26. Plus, I suggest you to do a `dd($month);` right after line 27 to be sure Carbon handle it. I think line 27 should be `$month = $subcription->month->month();`. Write me at elmorin89@gmail.com for more help. We are out of the track now with all those comments.